# Why is the plot of $\left|x\right|^{\frac{2}{3}}+\left|y\right|^{\frac{2}{3}}=4^{\frac{2}{3}}$ an astroid.

Tags: circles, cycloid

I was exploring the implicit function $\left|x\right|^{n}+\left|y\right|^n = 1$ and noticed that when $n$ is between 0 and 1 the plot looks similar to an astroid (The resulting curve of tracing a point that is rolling inside a circle with a radius that is 4 times greater) and I noticed that at exactly $n=2/3$ the 2 plots were the same. Is there any reason for this?
[Desmos demonstration](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yje72vhmni)

Comment: see the standard equation of an astroid here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid#:~:text=An%20astroid%20is%20a%20particular,4%2F3%20times%20the%20radius.

Comment: You should accept my answer, unless you have follow-up questions to ask!

Answer (score 1):

The astroid is a special case of a [hypocycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocycloid). If you take $k=4$ in the parametrization given in that link, you get
\begin{align*}
x &= 3\cos\theta + \cos 3\theta \\
y &= 3\sin\theta - \sin 3\theta.
\end{align*}
Now the triple angle identities (use deMoivre's formula if you know it, addition formulas in trigonometry otherwise) come to your rescue:
\begin{align*}
\cos 3\theta &= 4\cos^3\theta - 3\cos\theta \\
\sin 3\theta &= 3\sin\theta - 4\sin^3\theta.
\end{align*}
Inserting these, we find
\begin{align*}
x &= 4\cos^3\theta \\
y &= 4\sin^3\theta.
\end{align*}
Taking the $2/3$ power gives
\begin{align*}
|x|^{2/3} &= 4^{2/3}\cos^2\theta \\
|y|^{2/3} &= 4^{2/3}\sin^2\theta,
\end{align*}
from which we deduce that $|x|^{2/3} + |y|^{2/3} = 4^{2/3}$.

Comment: There are even more generic-like curves with similar formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto Thanks, although this comment might be better for the OP. :P

Comment: Exquisite but boring, sir.

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto I have no earthly idea what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: Neither do I...